# Hide generic type arguments behind concrete type results in CS0535

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I've a rather academic question: why is it technically not possible to use the following code?

```cs
// abstractions
public record MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity>(
    TContract Contract, TEntity Entity);

public interface IMapper<TResult, TContract, TEntity>
{
    TResult Map(MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity> request);
}

// more readable abstraction
public interface ILocationMapper
    : IMapper<LocationResult
    , LocationContract, LocationEntity>
{
}

// concrete
public record LocationResult;
public record LocationContract;
public record LocationEntity;

public record LocationRequest(LocationContract Contract, LocationEntity Entity)
    : MappingRequest<LocationContract
    , LocationEntity>(Contract, Entity);

public class LocationMapper : ILocationMapper
{
    public LocationResult Map(LocationRequest request)
    {
        return new LocationResult();
    }
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

> Error CS0535 : 'LocationMapper' does not implement interface member 'IMapper<LocationResult, LocationContract, LocationEntity>.Map(MappingRequest<LocationContract, LocationEntity>)'

Why can't the compiler not "infer" (not entirely sure whether this is the correct term here) that `LocationRequest` inherits from `MappingRequest`?

Comment: Why? Because `LocationMapper.Map` requires a `LocationRequest`, but an `IMapper` must accept _any_ `MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity>` in `Map`, not just `LocationRequest`.

Comment: But `LocationRequest` is a `MappingRequest`, no?

Comment: @mu88 - But not all `MappingRequest<...>` are a `LocationRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LocationMapper.Map` method currently accepts a `LocationRequest`, but any implementation of `IMapper<LocationResult, LocationContract, LocationEntity>` must implement a `Map` method that accepts *any* `MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity>`, not just `LocationRequest`.

Your code is simple, but imagine `LocationRequest` had a property `Foo`:

```
public record LocationRequest(LocationContract Contract, LocationEntity Entity)
    : MappingRequest<LocationContract, LocationEntity>(Contract, Entity)
{
    public string Foo { get; }
}
```

And your method tried to use that property:

```
public class LocationMapper : ILocationMapper
{
    public LocationResult Map(LocationRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.Foo);
        return new LocationResult();
    }
}
```

Now, if you try to call that as an `IMapper<LocationResult, LocationContract, LocationEntity>`, with another `MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity>`, we have a problem, because there is no `Foo` property.

e.g.

```
var request = new MappingRequest<TContract, TEntity>(default, default);
IMapper<LocationResult, LocationContract, LocationEntity> mapper
    = new LocationMapper();
mapper.Map(request); // We don't have any Foo to use !!
```

---

The problem is that `LocationRequest` isn't a simplified alias for `MappingRequest<LocationContract, LocationEntity>`, it's a completely different type altogether.

If verbosity is a problem for you, then you can alias your type like this:

```
using LocationRequest = MappingRequest<LocationContract, LocationEntity>;
```